# Are short sellers responsible for damages in a securities class action suit?

Tags: shorting-securities, lawsuit-settlement

Imagine that XYZ company was found liable for its misdeeds and its shareholders are awarded a compensation. Are the short sellers on the hook as well? That is, do they need to pay the amount of the award to their broker so that the broker can transfer it to the shareholder whose shares were lended for the short sale?

A reference to yes/no answer would be very helpful!

Comment: Good question to which I don't know the answer to.    Interesting read at: https://finops.co/investments/dole-class-action-ruling-short-selling-clawback-next/